# Render image in template.html with Jinja2 and weasyprint in a PDF

Tags: python, jinja2, weasyprint

I have a python file that generates an HTML page (and a PDF) using jinja2 like this.

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
from weasyprint import HTML

# Stuff to get dataframe...

# Generate PDF and csv
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('.'))
template = env.get_template("template.html")

template_vars = {"title" : "Something...",
                "vulnerabilities_table": df.to_html(index=False)}

html_out = template.render(template_vars)
HTML(string=html_out).write_pdf("report_styled.pdf", stylesheets=["style.css"])
```

It uses the following `template.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% block layout_style %}
<style> @page { size: letter landscape; margin: 2cm; } </style>

{% endblock %}
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="static/images/Logo.png" style="height: 100; width: 300; float:inline-start">
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
     {{ vulnerabilities_table }}
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the image is not rendering at all (but the rest does). I guess it's because I'm not using Flask

```html
<img src="static/images/Logo.png" style="height: 100; width: 300; float:inline-start">
```

My image is in the folder static/images/Logo.png. What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is not about Flask. It's about `weasyprint` converting html page  (it's actually html string in your case) to PDF. For `weasyprint` `HTML` class to fetch the `img` source (static/images/Logo.png), you need to put the full local file path as `file:///path/to/folder/static/images/Logo/png`.

What you can do is, in `template.html`:

```
<img src="{{ image_path }}" style="height: 100; width: 300; float:inline-start">
```

In python code:

```
import os
this_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
template_vars = {"title" : "Something...",
                "vulnerabilities_table": "hello world",
                 "image_path": 'file://' + os.path.join(this_folder, 'static', 'images', 'Logo.png' )}
html_out = template.render(template_vars)
HTML(string=html_out).write_pdf("report_styled.pdf", stylesheets=["style.css"])
```

Comment: You pointed right at the issue and the solution works perfectly. I totally missunderstood the problem. Changing the title to match accordingly.
Thanks